# Get CHAR_LENGTH of mysql entry as a php variable

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Thanks in advance for any help!

I have several different mysql columns (which are imported from a product feed) that I'm trying to convert into one to work with a custom plugin for Opencart.

The format of the MYSQL entry for the plugin is as follows...

```
a:11:{i:13;s:3:"964";i:14;s:9:"Automatic";i:15;s:3:"FWD";i:16;s:15:"Gas I6 4.2L/256";i:17;s:5:"Black";i:18;s:4:"Gray";i:19;s:12:"Some City, ST";i:20;s:2:"15";i:21;s:2:"21";i:22;s:6:"128365";i:23;s:17:"2XXXXG3XXXXH5XXXX";}
```

As you can see, the "s:X" represents the character count for each entry. I have 11 different columns with the info I'm trying to convert to this format, but without an accurate character count the plugin throws an error. So i'm trying to use a combo of sql/php to get an accurate character count that I can use to make this work. I have a handle on everything else.

SO!

My question is...how do I assign the character count to a variable? I did some googling and I found this...

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('TABLENAME');
```

I realize there's more to it, just wondering how to set it as a variable.

AND

<strike>Not terribly important, but does anyone recognize the format? I've never seen this before!</strike>
Serialized PHP Array

Comment: Wild guess but this looks like JSON.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools. Honestly, isn't your text awful like that ?

Comment: It's a serialized array, not JSON. You can turn it into a PHP array with `unserialize()`

Comment: wow, can't believe I've never encountered this before. It certainly looks like a serialized array now that I've looked at some examples. I could just assign all 11 columns to an array and serialize then, which makes life a lot easier(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help anyone in the future since this is pretty specific, but based on the info I got from jraede (thanks alot!). I was able to load all 11 columns into a PHP array and serialize, then upload to DB. WAY easier than trying to create 11 variables for character count!

Comment: I understand that using data serialization to store multiple information within one simple column is easy (and makes life easier) - but that is a common beginner mistake and it proves You do not look further than Your concrete problem (i.e. storing serialized data may bring other problems in the future - or quite soon). Have You heard about [database normalisation](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)? I know You didn't...

Comment: I'm working within the structure of an opencart plugin. I didn't choose the serialized array, and I may or may not have done it that way myself, but I see your point.